# Vuex: Cannot pass state in mutation in module pattern. Commit mutation without axios

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I want  to get `state` on my `mutations`.

I have `store.js` like :

```
export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    server: 'something'
  },
  modules: {
    Product,
    Cart
  }
})
```

Then, on my `product.js` module. I can get the `store` `server` in `getters` but cannot make use in `mutations`. P.s I need to  `commit` without `axios`..

```
export default{

    state :{
        abc: 'asdfasf'
    },

    getters :{
        getServer : (state, getters, rootState) =>{
            return rootState.server; //It works fine.
        },

    },
    mutations :{
        UPDATE(state,rootState){
            console.log(state.getters.getServer); //this wont work
            state.abc = rootState.serve; //something like this won't work 
            either
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to access `rootState` in mutations. But you can do it in `actions` and then call mutations to commit state

```
actions:  {
  updateServer ({commit, rootState}) {
    commit('UPDATE', rootState.serve)
  }
},
mutations: {
  UPDATE (state, payload){
     state.abc = payload
 }
}
```

Comment: It would've been really great if we were able to access it on mutations as  well.. anyway thanks